# WPF MVVM textbox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, textbox

**UPDATE**

I got it work with this custom implementation [here](https://github.com/Reverp/Toxy/blob/master/Toxy/MVVM/DelegateCommand.cs). There was a problem with weak references using prism.

I am new to MVVM and Microsofts Prism. I am trying to get my binding on my textbox to work. The login button should get available if the textbox is not empty. The setter is working but CanOnLogin() always returns false.

**Model**

```
class UserModel
{
    private string userName;
    private string passWord;
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }


    public string PassWord
    {
        get { return passWord; }
        set { passWord = value; }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private UserModel user;
    private DelegateCommand _loginCommand;
    public UserModel User 
    { 
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    } 

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return user.UserName; }
        set
        {
            user.UserName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get { return _loginCommand; }
    }

    public LoginViewModel() 
    {
        _loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnLogin, CanOnLogin);
        //implement CanOnLoginChanged here?
        user = new UserModel();
    }

    private bool CanOnLogin()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }

    private void OnLogin() 
    {
    // Do something here
        MessageBox.Show(user.UserName);
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event EventHandler CanOnLoginChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<TextBox Name="username" Text="{Binding Path=UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Width="175" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Username" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"/>
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Width="87.5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}">Login</Button>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class LoginView : MetroWindow
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't show your button here.

Comment: When I change CanOnLogin to return always true the button works.

Comment: yes problem is it is not reaching your condition once you have string not null, for that you have to imlement canexecutechaned correctly

Comment: code for your button please

Comment: Added it to the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **CanOnLogin** you should check against the Property from the ViewModel, that PropertyChanged can work:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName)
```

If that does not help, try to set up you command for lazy-loading to ensure all data is proper initialized first. Something like

```
public ICommand LoginCommand
{
    get { return _loginCommand ?? (_loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnLogin, CanOnLogin)); }
}
```

or change the Initialisation-Order in the LoginViewModel():

```
user = new UserModel();
_loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnLogin, CanOnLogin);
```

And you are right: **Prism** Delegate Command does not work always like I would expect. Reported [here](http://lookonmyworks.co.uk/2013/02/05/weak-references-and-the-prism-delegatecommand/).

Checkout this [Example](https://github.com/Reverp/Toxy/blob/master/Toxy/MVVM/DelegateCommand.cs) of a custom Implementation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did these changes but same result. It does not work.

Comment: It does not work. I will try that custom implementation. EDIT: Custom implementation works :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have to create canExecuteChanged:
it will work now.

```
 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
```

can execute will check if there is any related event that could change the state and will change the state from false to true if finds one.

Comment: I implemented CanExecuteChanged but it does not work neither. As I understand this event correctly I have to insert it into my ViewModel.

Comment: dont use can execute changed as you have used onlogin and canonlogin so canonloginchanged

Comment: I do not get it work. I watched for some examples how to subscribe to the event but did not find a solution. Can you help me?

Comment: tell me how you r implementing this show code for viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were not passsing object parameter as arguments to OnLogin and CanOnLogin that is why it was not working for me it did and implement canOnLogInChanged not inside any property or method instead where I did, or just take this code and try again:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private UserModel user;
    private DelegateCommand _loginCommand;
    public UserModel User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return user.UserName; }
        set
        {
            user.UserName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get { return _loginCommand; }
    }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        _loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnLogin, CanOnLogin);
        //implement CanOnLoginChanged here?
        user = new UserModel();
    }

    private bool CanOnLogin(object parameter)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler CanOnLoginChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
    private void OnLogin(object parameter)
    {
        // Do something here
        MessageBox.Show(user.UserName);
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried to implement youre solution and getting following error: Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'. I did some investigation but could not find a solution that helped me. It seems to be a problem with DelegateCommand from prism.